# I have a facebook page access token which expires in 1 hour.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, datasift-python

Could someone say how can i extend  the validity of the access token. The permission which i am giving to access token are manage_pages and publish_pages

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#generate-long-lived-token Just google it please... lol

Comment: Bro not a joke. Thanks for your response by the way. I tried doing it. I am getting this error:

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "E57pyVgH+HR"
  }
}

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/mar/21/mark-zuckerberg-response-facebook-cambridge-analytica This shows up on a SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417886/why-does-facebook-graph-api-say-my-account-is-non-active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the answer is that unfortunately you can't (until further notice from Facebook).

Currently Facebook has been locking down this ability due to the security issues they are having. Until yesterday afternoon you could even cheat and create a "never expire" access token using a loophole. But as of today they have locked that down as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 hour expiry is because it is a short lived token. You want to then request again with your secret so that you can get a long lived token that expires in 60 days. Explanation from FB devs is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens