# Cannot access the Page API at all for a newly created app and page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to do new development on the FB platform post-Cambridge Analytica. Two days ago - i.e. after the review and restrictions started - I created a new FB app and a new Page. Using the Graph API Explorer, I can call `/me/` on my new page when the selected app is the Explorer app:

[image: Graph API Explorer - call works]

However, when I use my new app, I get the infamous OAuth error about "non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data":

[image: My app - call breaks]

The page access tokens for the two calls have the same permissions, the defaults Graph API Explorer uses:

[image: Graph API Explorer page access token]
[image: My app page access token]

I'm aware of this question that deals with the general case of this error: [Why does Facebook Graph API say my account is non-active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417886/why-does-facebook-graph-api-say-my-account-is-non-active)

However, some of the answers to it hint that either having "a first-party relationship" is what determines if I'm allowed access, or not asking for specific fields; and it seems to be about applications that worked before the drama and stopped working after. My app and page are new, created and admined by my account, I can hardly have a more first-party relationship than that; and I'm not asking any fields that aren't publically available for the page anyway. I've tried publishing and unpublishing the page, as well as having the app be in development or live.

Is there any way to actually start a new FB app before the dust settles? Or does "not active or hasn't recently accessed the data" mean only apps that were live and connected to the given pages before the clampdown can work?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-4: _“All new apps must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the [Pages] API”_

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I didn’t find that one, just the vague PR-ish statements. That said, how exactly I’m supposed to pass review with an app I can’t begin to write is beyond me.

Comment: Also, Facebook's review guide mentions (albeit only for the Login review guide) that administrators, developers, and testers of an app have access to all permissions. I guess if they're reworking the whole shebang this just ended up as collateral? What a mess.